# Rake gems:install yields error when following declarative authorization Railscast

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, declarative-authorization

I'm following Railstcast #188 to get declarative authorization running on my Rails 3 app (using Ruby 1.9.2) and am running into an issue getting the gem to install.

Ryan suggests adding it in `config/environment.rb` with the following:

```
config.gem "declarative_authorization", :source => "http://gemcutter.org"
```

Then install it with `sudo rake gems:install`.

However when I try that I get an error:

```
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:314:in `bin_path': can't find gem rake ([">= 0"]) with executable rake (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

I tried `rake gems:install`, but got this error:

```
Don't know how to build task 'gems:install'
```

The instructions to install declarative_authorization at [GitHub](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) recommend a different process, which I also followed but still couldn't get past `rake:gems install`.

Does anyone know what may be happening so I can get around this?

**UPDATE:** Here's what my config/environment.rb looks like:

RVM -v: `rvm 1.10.0-pre`
Gem list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.9, 3.0.5)
actionpack (3.0.9, 3.0.5)
activemodel (3.0.9, 3.0.5)
activerecord (3.0.9, 3.0.5)
activeresource (3.0.9, 3.0.5)
activesupport (3.0.9, 3.0.5)
addressable (2.2.6)
arel (2.0.10)
aws-s3 (0.6.2)
aws-sdk (1.3.2)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.21 ruby)
cocaine (0.2.1, 0.2.0)
erubis (2.6.6)
faraday (0.7.6, 0.7.5)
fastercsv (1.5.4)
gemcutter (0.7.1)
heroku (2.14.0)
httparty (0.8.1)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.19, 1.0.16)
json (1.6.5)
launchy (2.0.5)
mail (2.2.19)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.17.2)
mocha (0.10.3, 0.10.2, 0.10.0)
multi_json (1.0.4)
multi_xml (0.4.1)
multipart-post (1.1.4)
nifty-generators (0.4.6)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
paperclip (2.5.2, 2.5.0, 2.4.5)
pg (0.12.2, 0.12.0, 0.11.0)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.2.5, 1.2.4)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.9, 3.0.5)
railties (3.0.9, 3.0.5)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rake-compiler (0.7.9)
ransack (0.6.0, 0.5.8)
rdoc (3.8)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rubyzip (0.9.5)
simple_oauth (0.1.5)
sqlite3 (1.3.5, 1.3.4)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.10)
twitter (2.1.0, 2.0.2)
tzinfo (0.3.31, 0.3.30)
uuidtools (2.1.2)
xml-simple (1.1.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your environment is set up, but simply installing rake should do it. If you provide more detail (rvm, bundler, etc.) it may be of help.

```
gem install rake
```

Upon further inspection of your path, I see you're using RVM.  If your paths are installed properly, you can either use the RVM Global gemset, execute the line above.

Another suggestion I have is checking out the CanCan railscast as that is the bigger norm for authorization these days, more supporters as well.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

"A few episodes ago we covered Declarative Authorization. While it is an excellent authorization plugin for Rails it can be a little heavy for simpler sites. After writing the Railscast on Declarative Authorization Ryan Bates looked for an alternative solution and, failing to find one that suited his needs, decided to write his own, CanCan." - RBates

After seeing your environment, let's try to separate the environments a little.  Do this.

```
rvm gemset create some_other_name
rvm gemset use some_other_name
bundle install
```

See if this isolates your environment enough.

EDIT: I don't use rake gems:install anymore.  You have bundler installed, and I'm assuming you want to use it.  I do use rails g gemname:install when the documentation for such exists, I'm going to look at the railscasts again and see what rbates is telling you.

On the CANCAN github page, it says: In Rails 3, add this to your Gemfile and run the bundle command.
gem "cancan".

Comment: I'm happy to give more detail. I'll paste as an update above.

Comment: notice also I modified slightly.  I think using CanCan will get you better support and Ryan developed it to cover gaps in the declartive auth gem as stated in that railscasts.

Comment: Hm, alright I may check out CanCan then. Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still curious as to what's going on.

Comment: So if I try to install CanCan following the Railscast it requires the same `sudo rake gems:install`, which gives me the same error as I document above.

Comment: Hmm, I'm interested in your RVM setup. It sounds like it can't find the path of your gems.  Try gem list --local, what's that say.  Looks like you updated that. Try gem uninstall rake... and uninstall 0.9.2.2 and 0.8.7 (well that's my preference).

Comment: I may just go with the Gemfile on github as you referenced. Thank you for detailed responses!

Comment: rake gems:install is something I used in rails 2, and I get headaches when trying to go back to that age.  If you're using rails 3 and rvm, I'd suggest doing it the rails 3 way, and also use bundler.  I believe that's the new default.